# neither did she jump nor sing

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice, neither-nor

What is the correct way of using "neither nor"?

1. Alex neither jumped nor sang.
2. Neither **did** she **jump** nor sing.
3. Neither **jumped** she **nor** sang.

Answer (score 1):

1. is the usual format.
2. is framed more like a line from a poem, as though required for the metre and rhyme. While unusual, it's legitimate in poetry or verse:

**With injured claw and wounded wing, neither did she jump nor sing.**

3. is possible but again only in poetic or dramatic contexts. It sounds very old fashioned, as though taken from some Arthurian tale.

Answer (score 0):

I think expression 2 should be
Neither did she jump **or** sing.

I don't think *neither* and *nor* are coordinated in your example 2.

The word *neither* attaches to the entire following phrase, and it must refer to something that came before, for example,

*She didn't smile or laugh; neither did she jump or sing.*